# Why does GitHub check not reflect Azure Pipelines build status?

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to add Azure Pipelines configuration to an existing project, `bundler/bundler`. Here is the PR that adds the configuration:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/6899

As one of the maintainers set up the `bundler/bundler` project on Azure Pipelines, this PR already triggers a build:
https://dev.azure.com/bundler/bundler/_build/results?buildId=11
Note that the build has a green checkmark and is marked as finished.

(Also note that there are *loads* of tests failing in the build, as this wasn't tested on Windows before. To make the build succeed anyway - and not *all* PRs and commits get the red "x" on Github while I am working on fixing the tests, I added `|| exit 0` at the end of the test command - which works fine on Azure Pipelines)

A feature of Azure Pipelines' GitHub integration is that the build results are shown in Github via a feature called "Check":
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/6899/checks

(A shorter version of that is also included at the end of the PR page: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/6899#partial-pull-merging)

Unfortunately, this check doesn't reflect the build status on Azure Pipelines and is still shown as "in progress":

[image: check status on check page]

and

[image: check status on PR page]

Any idea why the GitHub check doesn't reflect the build status on Azure Pipelines?

---

What is confusing me further, is that the integration with Azure Pipelines actually worked just fine (check correctly reflects the build status) in the Pull Request that was automatically created by Azure Pipelines when creating the `bundler/bundler` project: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/6955

But: It also can't really be the Azure Pipelines configuration I created in my PR, because the same configuration also works just fine in my fork: https://github.com/janpio/bundler/pull/6#partial-timeline (see the green checkmark for the bundler task). (On the other hand: Here Azure Pipelines doesn't use the "Check" feature of Github at all)

Comment: I also contacted Microsoft Azure Pipelines support about this and opened an "Incident Report" (as told by their Twitter account). Unfortunately the first response of their "Support Professionsal" was pretty off topic :/

Comment: Sorry that your initial response was less than helpful; requeuing the build should work but feel free to message me on twitter (@ethomson) if you still have any trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.  The *most likely* reason is that there some was glitch in the communication between Azure Pipelines and GitHub.  It's very rare but sometimes a webhook between GitHub and Azure Pipelines doesn't trigger.  There's no way to tell why it happened; it could have been a fault on either side.

Unfortunately, there's no way to re-send a webhook that didn't get delivered.  Your only recourse is to rebuild that pull request.  If you select the "Rebuild" option (in the `...` menu):

[image]

Then a new build will be queued and, when it finishes, the status update will be sent back to GitHub.  The check in the pull request will then be updated.

---

A less likely (but definitely possible) reason is that there's a bug in either Azure Pipelines or GitHub.  And in *this* particular case, there was a bug with the code that uploads test results from Azure Pipelines to the test case manager API.

(Thanks for reporting the issue, we're sorry that we had a bit of a problem here, but we're glad that we were able to resolve this.)

Comment: Thanks @Edward Thomson for your answer. Unfortunately I am not added to that project on Azure Pipelines and also will not be, as I am not a maintainer or member of the bundler team - just a random guy from the internet suggesting a Pull Request.

Comment: But: I don't think this would help. I created a new branch with the same content and opened a new Pull Request to the repository, and it has the exact same problem: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/6960 vs. https://dev.azure.com/bundler/bundler/_build/results?buildId=12 So I think it might have to do with the configuration somehow after all. (Maybe the `|| exit 0`?)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the following configuration worked for me:

[image]